# How to pan to some point or marker using jQuery Google Map UI v3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I check all the method in the jQuery Google Map v3 api, there is no pan. I found example of v2, there is a map.panTo method, but not working in v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

V3 still has `map.panTo(my_latlon);`. Also a `.panBy(` but that's besides the point.
I currently have an application that uses V3 and also uses these methods, so I know it works.

Answer (score 2):

The `map.panTo(latLng:LatLng)` function seems to work for me:

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/D2W3j/)